# How to limit jobs in an indicated queue in SGE

Tags: cluster, gridengine

I have two queues in SGE for different purposes. Each of them has a limit in slots. What I want is to have only a certain number of jobs submitted to a queue waiting even when the other queue is idle. However, what I found is the additional jobs were assigned to the second queue.  How should I change the configuration?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You want jobs to wait for a queue to become available, up until you reach a certain number of jobs, and only then utilize the other queue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the queue name when submitting:

`qsub -l qname=<queue name> ...`

Then the other queue will not be used.